# Should users be allowed to ban themselves?

Tags: user-behavior

This question was asked in chat: [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16879234#16879234), understandably this network can be taxing on one's time. If so, where do I apply?

Comment: If you are asking if this feature should be implemented on Stack Exchange then you are in the wrong place.

Comment: Where would the right place be to implement and *execute* this feature?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If it's a feature request for SE then post on [meta.se].

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why not. It could be a selling point for your forum if people can take voluntary enforced time outs.

One danger I'd see is "friends" requesting a timeout when someone leaves themselves logged in on an unlocked machine. You'd have to treat the request the same as you would a password change or account deletion request - e-mail the user asking them if they're sure and only start the timeout when then click on the link in the e-mail.

You might also need to include a "let me back in early" option. However, if this was a manual process you wouldn't want people to be continually requesting bans then changing their minds.

Comment: I'm reminded of Facebook's account deactivation, which is really just a fancy way to log out.